# Fix divs at certain scroll point then unfix at another scroll point

Tags: css, html, fixed, horizontal-scrolling

I am working on a website with divs that I want to fix at a certain scroll point but then become unfixed at another scroll point.I've looked at other similar posts on how to fix a div at certain points but thats only the first part of the event I want to create. Also my website is horizontally scrolling and all the posts I have looked at are for vertical scrolling.

I am a complete beginner at Javascript so don't even know where to start with the code! But I essentially want this:

```
/* When scrolling left  */
if (div >= 300 && div <= 600)
  position = fixed;
else 
  position = absolute;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have solved it! :D It's a bit sloppy, probs not the cleanest/most efficient code ever but it does what I need:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if  ($(window).scrollLeft() <= 3600){
     $('#section2').css({position:'relative'});
} 
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if  ($(window).scrollLeft() >= 3600){
     $('#section2').css({position:'fixed',padding:'0px',margin:'0px',});

} 
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if  ($(window).scrollLeft() >= 4900){
     $('#section2').css({position:'relative', paddingLeft:'1200px'});
} 
});
```

I just used "if" statements instead of "if" and "else" to set the div to relative before and after my fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with pure CSS but take a look at this jQuery plugin http://stickyjs.com.

```
$(function(){
  $('div').sticky(options);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would this plugin work for horizontal scrolling though as it only has topSpacing and bottomSpacing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about horizontal scrolling